# Where does spring boot configure default application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot

By default Spring Boot will automatically load properties from      `classpath:/application.properties`

I want to know where is this auto configuration source code. 
I want to exclude from my app. 
IE: `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=XXXXAutoconfiguration.class)`

The reason is:
Because I cannot override the default application.properties by an external property using `@PropertySource`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test.green.ws"})
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:/application.properties", "file:/opt/green-ws/application.properties"})
public class GreenWSApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GreenWSApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to override property keys without disabling the whole externalized configuration feature; and that's actually the goal.

You can see [here the order the properties are considered in](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html). For example, you can add that external properties file in a `config` folder right next to the packaged JAR, or even [configure the file location yourself](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files).

Now if you **really** want to disable all of that (and the Boot team strongly suggests not to do that), you can register your own `EnvironmentPostProcessor` ([see here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-boot-application.html#howto-customize-the-environment-or-application-context)) and remove `PropertySources` from `MutablePropertySources`, which you can fetch with `configurableEnvironment. getPropertySources()`.

There's no easier way to do that because:

1. this comes really early in the application init phase, before auto-configurations
2. this is not something you should do, as it will have many side effects

Comment: Yes I can override configuration by either using the program agurments and config folder. But I still want to know how to disable spring boot properties configuration. Is there anyway to achieve that?

Comment: updated my answer; if you ever encounter a bug with Boot, please mention all those non-recommended customizations if you raise an issue on the bug tracker.